# Read keys and values from Observable in Angular Template?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I have been trying to show all the keys and all the values from an Observable returned by Angular Firebase Fire Store Collection.

This is how I connect to the collection, and returned an Observable. I call the function later.

```
verOrden : any;

blunt() {

this.afStore.collection(`Something`).valueChanges().subscribe(res => (this.verOrden = res));  

}
```

I can perflecty read each value if a give the key in the template:

```
<ion-card *ngFor = "let item of verOrden">

        <ion-card-content>

            {{item.descripcion}}

        </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>
```

Where description is the key inside of the observable.

But I want to read all the values and the keys inside of the observable, without me giving each one.

I have tried this, but does not work.

```
<ion-card *ngFor = "let item of verOrden | keyvalue">

        <ion-card-content>

            {{item.descripcion.key}}

        </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>
```

I want the key and the value to be show.

Answer (score 0):

`keyvalue` [returns an array of objects that have `key` and `value` for keys](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe). So your `item` in the loop has shape `{ key: ___, value: ___ }`. But you're trying to access `.description`.

You can quickly check out the structure [by using the `json` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe):

```
<ion-card *ngFor = "let item of verOrden | keyvalue">
    <ion-card-content>
        {{ item | json }}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

What you want is probably this:

```
<ion-card *ngFor = "let item of verOrden | keyvalue">
    <ion-card-content>
        {{ item.key.descripcion }}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: I almost gave up, thanks you man! The .description, my bad while posting the question. I just did a little change, actually I use  {{ item.value | json }} to get what I wanted. Thank you, again man!